# Dataset until the first appearance of a word

Tags: r, tidyverse

Ok, guys, the idea is: I need to subset a dataframe, from row 1 to the row that a certain word appears, in this case `"PInd"`. I couldn't find anything to help me in this problem. I tried:

```
dftest <- df[1:which(df$Date[starts_with("PInd")])]
```

I also tried:

```
dftest <- df[1:select(df$Date, starts_with("PInd"))]
```

It gives the following error:

> Error: No tidyselect variables were registered.

I really don't what else I can do. Hope I made myself clear here. Any thoughts?

Comment: `starts_with` finds column names, not values within a column. Perhaps you want `grep` or `grepl`?

Comment: @r2evans Ow, that was so simple. Thanks a lot, Evans!